# der, die oder das Dock (quick launch bar)?

Tags: grammar, gender

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl heißt die Schnellstartleiste *das* Dock, so wie auch das http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dock aus der Schifffahrt. Auch der Wikipedia-Artikel gibt mir recht (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(Software)).

Ich lese allerdings immer wieder, dass Leute *die* Dock oder *der* Dock schreiben. Was ist nun richtig?

Comment: Ich habe die oder der Dock noch nie gesehen; kannst du mir eine Quelle geben? :)

Comment: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/blob/master/po/de.po (wegen dieser Übersetzung in dem Programm hat sich mir die Frage auch überhaupt gestellt), http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/nexus-dock-eine-dock-fuer-windows/, http://moodle2.unifr.ch/mod/page/view.php?id=16342, http://www.neuropool.com/berichte/technologie/wie-sperrt-und-entsperrt-man-den-mac-dock-.html

Comment: In diesem Zusammenhang klingt "Dock" für meine Ohren ziemlich ungewohnt, ich würde wohl eher "Dockingleiste" sagen - wo das Geschlecht klar ist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Da *das* Dock in der Schifffahrt schon existiert, wüsste ich nicht, warum man etwas Neues erfinden muss. Am Dock legen Schiffe an, an der Schnellstartleiste kann man genauso Programme anlegen (lassen). Die Metapher könnte doch gar nicht besser sein!

Ich würde sagen, dass die Dock oder der Dock schlicht falsch sind.